# How to reduce the CSS lines - Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

For my WordPress website, I need to style H1 and H2 tags on specific pages, so How can I reduce the number of lines of this CSS code?

.page-id-1427 h1 {color:red}

.page-id-1427 h2 {color:red}

.page-id-1428 h1 {color:red}

.page-id-1428 h2 {color:red}

.page-id-1429 h1 {color:red}

.page-id-1429 h2 {color:red}

.page-id-1430 h1 {color:red}

.page-id-1430 h2 {color:red}

...And the list goes on

I need to style only the color of H1, H2 tags.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add them together like so:-

```
.page-id-1428 h2, .page-id-1429 h1, .page-id-1429 h2 ...
{color:red}
```

Comment: Great, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can specify like  this:

```
h1,h2 {color:red}
```